# Getting value using div id into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to turn an HTML id to a Javascript variable, the reason is I want to retrieve another variable from another file, I ended up having the variable in HTML format, and I would like to use that variable in the javascript script. Is there a simple way to solve this problem? Because my code doesn't seem to be working. Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <div id="theVariable">13579</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var converted = document.getElementById("theVariable").value;
    //var converted = document.getElementById("theVariable");
    document.write(converted);
    document.write(" something else");
  </script>
</head>

<!---------out put should be: --------
13579
13579 something else
--------------------------------------->
```

Comment: Have you tried to include the link of javascript file on `<script>` instead of print it all on HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the attribute `value` on a `div` element which wont work. Use `innerhtml` instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <div id="theVariable">13579</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var converted = document.getElementById("theVariable").innerHTML;
    //var converted = document.getElementById("theVariable");
    document.write(converted);
    document.write(" something else");
  </script>
</head>

<!---------out put should be: --------
13579
13579 something else
--------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textContent` & `trim`.`trim` will remove any white space

```js
var converted = document.getElementById("theVariable").textContent.trim();
console.log(converted)
```

```html
<div id="theVariable">13579</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.value uses to get value in input tag. for div/span/p, we should use innerHTML